# variable assignment in Pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to read some pine script to understand how it works.

But there is some strange thing I can't explain.

For exemple for pivot pine script:

```
pivotX_open = float(na)
pivotX_open := nz(pivotX_open[1], open)
pivotX_high = float(na)
pivotX_high := nz(pivotX_high[1], high)
pivotX_low = float(na)
pivotX_low := nz(pivotX_low[1], low)
pivotX_prev_open = float(na)
pivotX_prev_open := nz(pivotX_prev_open[1])
pivotX_prev_high = float(na)
pivotX_prev_high := nz(pivotX_prev_high[1])
pivotX_prev_low = float(na)
pivotX_prev_low := nz(pivotX_prev_low[1])
pivotX_prev_close = float(na)
pivotX_prev_close := nz(pivotX_prev_close[1])
```

I can't understand these inits.
It seems to be a commun way to do, but it's hard to understand how a variable can be initialized with itself.

Thanks for you help.

The complete code from Tradingview

```
//@version=5
indicator("Pivot Points Standard", "Pivots", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500)

AUTO = "Auto"
DAILY = "Daily"
WEEKLY = "Weekly"
MONTHLY = "Monthly"
QUARTERLY = "Quarterly"
YEARLY = "Yearly"
BIYEARLY = "Biyearly"
TRIYEARLY = "Triyearly"
QUINQUENNIALLY = "Quinquennially"
DECENNIALLY = "Decennially"

TRADITIONAL = "Traditional"
FIBONACCI = "Fibonacci"
WOODIE = "Woodie"
CLASSIC = "Classic"
DEMARK = "DM"
CAMARILLA = "Camarilla"

kind = input.string(title="Type", defval="Traditional", options=[TRADITIONAL, FIBONACCI, WOODIE, CLASSIC, DEMARK, CAMARILLA])
pivot_time_frame = input.string(title="Pivots Timeframe", defval=AUTO, options=[AUTO, DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY, QUARTERLY, YEARLY, BIYEARLY, TRIYEARLY, QUINQUENNIALLY, DECENNIALLY])
look_back = input.int(title="Number of Pivots Back", defval=15, minval=1, maxval=5000)
is_daily_based = input.bool(title="Use Daily-based Values", defval=true, tooltip="When this option is unchecked, Pivot Points will use intraday data while calculating on intraday charts. If Extended Hours are displayed on the chart, they will be taken into account during the pivot level calculation. If intraday OHLC values are different from daily-based values (normal for stocks), the pivot levels will also differ.")
show_labels = input.bool(title="Show Labels", defval=true, inline="labels")
position_labels = input.string("Left", "", options=["Left", "Right"], inline="labels")

var DEF_COLOR = #FB8C00
var arr_time = array.new_int()
var p = array.new_float()
p_show = input.bool(true, "P‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏", inline="P")
p_color = input.color(DEF_COLOR, "", inline="P")
var r1 = array.new_float()
var s1 = array.new_float()
s1r1_show = input.bool(true, "S1/R1", inline="S1/R1")
s1r1_color = input.color(DEF_COLOR, "", inline="S1/R1")
var r2 = array.new_float()
var s2 = array.new_float()
s2r2_show = input.bool(true, "S2/R2", inline="S2/R2")
s2r2_color = input.color(DEF_COLOR, "", inline="S2/R2")
var r3 = array.new_float()
var s3 = array.new_float()
s3r3_show = input.bool(true, "S3/R3", inline="S3/R3")
s3r3_color = input.color(DEF_COLOR, "", inline="S3/R3")
var r4 = array.new_float()
var s4 = array.new_float()
s4r4_show = input.bool(true, "S4/R4", inline="S4/R4")
s4r4_color = input.color(DEF_COLOR, "", inline="S4/R4")
var r5 = array.new_float()
var s5 = array.new_float()
s5r5_show = input.bool(true, "S5/R5", inline="S5/R5")
s5r5_color = input.color(DEF_COLOR, "", inline="S5/R5")
pivotX_open = float(na)
pivotX_open := nz(pivotX_open[1], open)
pivotX_high = float(na)
pivotX_high := nz(pivotX_high[1], high)
pivotX_low = float(na)
pivotX_low := nz(pivotX_low[1], low)
pivotX_prev_open = float(na)
pivotX_prev_open := nz(pivotX_prev_open[1])
pivotX_prev_high = float(na)
pivotX_prev_high := nz(pivotX_prev_high[1])
pivotX_prev_low = float(na)
pivotX_prev_low := nz(pivotX_prev_low[1])
pivotX_prev_close = float(na)
pivotX_prev_close := nz(pivotX_prev_close[1])

get_pivot_resolution() =>
    resolution = "M"
    if pivot_time_frame == AUTO
        if timeframe.isintraday
            resolution := timeframe.multiplier <= 15 ? "D" : "W"
        else if timeframe.isweekly or timeframe.ismonthly
            resolution := "12M"
    else if pivot_time_frame == DAILY
        resolution := "D"
    else if pivot_time_frame == WEEKLY
        resolution := "W"
    else if pivot_time_frame == MONTHLY
        resolution := "M"
    else if pivot_time_frame == QUARTERLY
        resolution := "3M"
    else if pivot_time_frame == YEARLY or pivot_time_frame == BIYEARLY or pivot_time_frame == TRIYEARLY or pivot_time_frame == QUINQUENNIALLY or pivot_time_frame == DECENNIALLY
        resolution := "12M"
    resolution

var lines = array.new_line()
var labels = array.new_label()

draw_line(i, pivot, col) =>
    if array.size(arr_time) > 1
        array.push(lines, line.new(array.get(arr_time, i), array.get(pivot, i), array.get(arr_time, i + 1), array.get(pivot, i), color=col, xloc=xloc.bar_time))

draw_label(i, y, txt, txt_color) =>
    if show_labels
        offset = '‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏'
        labels_align_str_left= position_labels == "Left" ? txt + offset : offset + txt
        x = position_labels == "Left" ? array.get(arr_time, i) : array.get(arr_time, i + 1)
        array.push(labels, label.new(x = x, y=y, text=labels_align_str_left, textcolor=txt_color, style=label.style_label_center, color=#00000000, xloc=xloc.bar_time))

traditional() =>
    pivotX_Median = (pivotX_prev_high + pivotX_prev_low + pivotX_prev_close) / 3
    array.push(p, pivotX_Median)
    array.push(r1, pivotX_Median * 2 - pivotX_prev_low)
    array.push(s1, pivotX_Median * 2 - pivotX_prev_high)
    array.push(r2, pivotX_Median + 1 * (pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low))
    array.push(s2, pivotX_Median - 1 * (pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low))
    array.push(r3, pivotX_Median * 2 + (pivotX_prev_high - 2 * pivotX_prev_low))
    array.push(s3, pivotX_Median * 2 - (2 * pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low))
    array.push(r4, pivotX_Median * 3 + (pivotX_prev_high - 3 * pivotX_prev_low))
    array.push(s4, pivotX_Median * 3 - (3 * pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low))
    array.push(r5, pivotX_Median * 4 + (pivotX_prev_high - 4 * pivotX_prev_low))
    array.push(s5, pivotX_Median * 4 - (4 * pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low))

fibonacci() =>
    pivotX_Median = (pivotX_prev_high + pivotX_prev_low + pivotX_prev_close) / 3
    pivot_range = pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low
    array.push(p, pivotX_Median)
    array.push(r1, pivotX_Median + 0.382 * pivot_range)
    array.push(s1, pivotX_Median - 0.382 * pivot_range)
    array.push(r2, pivotX_Median + 0.618 * pivot_range)
    array.push(s2, pivotX_Median - 0.618 * pivot_range)
    array.push(r3, pivotX_Median + 1 * pivot_range)
    array.push(s3, pivotX_Median - 1 * pivot_range)

woodie() =>
    pivotX_Woodie_Median = (pivotX_prev_high + pivotX_prev_low + pivotX_open * 2)/4
    pivot_range = pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low
    array.push(p, pivotX_Woodie_Median)
    array.push(r1, pivotX_Woodie_Median * 2 - pivotX_prev_low)
    array.push(s1, pivotX_Woodie_Median * 2 - pivotX_prev_high)
    array.push(r2, pivotX_Woodie_Median + 1 * pivot_range)
    array.push(s2, pivotX_Woodie_Median - 1 * pivot_range)

    pivot_point_r3 = pivotX_prev_high + 2 * (pivotX_Woodie_Median - pivotX_prev_low)
    pivot_point_s3 = pivotX_prev_low - 2 * (pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_Woodie_Median)
    array.push(r3, pivot_point_r3)
    array.push(s3, pivot_point_s3)
    array.push(r4, pivot_point_r3 + pivot_range)
    array.push(s4, pivot_point_s3 - pivot_range)

classic() =>
    pivotX_Median = (pivotX_prev_high + pivotX_prev_low + pivotX_prev_close)/3
    pivot_range = pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low
    array.push(p, pivotX_Median)
    array.push(r1, pivotX_Median * 2 - pivotX_prev_low)
    array.push(s1, pivotX_Median * 2 - pivotX_prev_high)
    array.push(r2, pivotX_Median + 1 * pivot_range)
    array.push(s2, pivotX_Median - 1 * pivot_range)
    array.push(r3, pivotX_Median + 2 * pivot_range)
    array.push(s3, pivotX_Median - 2 * pivot_range)
    array.push(r4, pivotX_Median + 3 * pivot_range)
    array.push(s4, pivotX_Median - 3 * pivot_range)

demark() =>
    pivotX_Demark_X = pivotX_prev_high + pivotX_prev_low * 2 + pivotX_prev_close
    if pivotX_prev_close == pivotX_prev_open
        pivotX_Demark_X := pivotX_prev_high + pivotX_prev_low + pivotX_prev_close * 2
    if pivotX_prev_close > pivotX_prev_open
        pivotX_Demark_X := pivotX_prev_high * 2 + pivotX_prev_low + pivotX_prev_close
    array.push(p, pivotX_Demark_X / 4)
    array.push(r1, pivotX_Demark_X / 2 - pivotX_prev_low)
    array.push(s1, pivotX_Demark_X / 2 - pivotX_prev_high)

camarilla() =>
    pivotX_Median = (pivotX_prev_high + pivotX_prev_low + pivotX_prev_close) / 3
    pivot_range = pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low
    array.push(p, pivotX_Median)
    array.push(r1, pivotX_prev_close + pivot_range * 1.1 / 12.0)
    array.push(s1, pivotX_prev_close - pivot_range * 1.1 / 12.0)
    array.push(r2, pivotX_prev_close + pivot_range * 1.1 / 6.0)
    array.push(s2, pivotX_prev_close - pivot_range * 1.1 / 6.0)
    array.push(r3, pivotX_prev_close + pivot_range * 1.1 / 4.0)
    array.push(s3, pivotX_prev_close - pivot_range * 1.1 / 4.0)
    array.push(r4, pivotX_prev_close + pivot_range * 1.1 / 2.0)
    array.push(s4, pivotX_prev_close - pivot_range * 1.1 / 2.0)

resolution = get_pivot_resolution()

[sec_open, sec_high, sec_low, sec_close] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, [open, high, low, close], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
sec_open_gaps_on = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, open, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

custom_years_divisor = switch pivot_time_frame
    BIYEARLY => 2
    TRIYEARLY => 3
    QUINQUENNIALLY => 5
    DECENNIALLY => 10
    => -1

is_change_years = false 
if custom_years_divisor > 0 and ta.change(time(resolution))
    is_change_years := year % custom_years_divisor == 0



var is_change = false
var uses_current_bar = timeframe.isintraday and kind == WOODIE
var change_time = int(na)
is_time_change = (ta.change(time(resolution)) and custom_years_divisor == -1) or is_change_years
if is_time_change
    change_time := time


if (not uses_current_bar and is_time_change) or (uses_current_bar and not na(sec_open_gaps_on))
    if is_daily_based and custom_years_divisor == -1
        pivotX_prev_open := sec_open[1]
        pivotX_prev_high := sec_high[1]
        pivotX_prev_low := sec_low[1]
        pivotX_prev_close := sec_close[1]
        pivotX_open := sec_open
        pivotX_high := sec_high
        pivotX_low := sec_low
    else
        pivotX_prev_high := pivotX_high
        pivotX_prev_low := pivotX_low
        pivotX_prev_open := pivotX_open
        pivotX_open := open
        pivotX_high := high
        pivotX_low := low
        pivotX_prev_close := close[1]

    if barstate.islast and not is_change and  array.size(arr_time) > 0
        array.set(arr_time, array.size(arr_time) - 1, change_time)
    else
        array.push(arr_time, change_time)

    if kind == TRADITIONAL
        traditional()
    else if kind == FIBONACCI
        fibonacci()
    else if kind == WOODIE
        woodie()
    else if kind == CLASSIC
        classic()
    else if kind == DEMARK
        demark()
    else if kind == CAMARILLA
        camarilla()

    if array.size(arr_time) > look_back
        if array.size(arr_time) > 0
            array.shift(arr_time)
        if array.size(p) > 0 and p_show
            array.shift(p)
        if array.size(r1) > 0 and s1r1_show
            array.shift(r1)
        if array.size(s1) > 0 and s1r1_show
            array.shift(s1)
        if array.size(r2) > 0 and s2r2_show
            array.shift(r2)
        if array.size(s2) > 0 and s2r2_show
            array.shift(s2)
        if array.size(r3) > 0 and s3r3_show
            array.shift(r3)
        if array.size(s3) > 0 and s3r3_show
            array.shift(s3)
        if array.size(r4) > 0 and s4r4_show
            array.shift(r4)
        if array.size(s4) > 0 and s4r4_show
            array.shift(s4)
        if array.size(r5) > 0 and s5r5_show
            array.shift(r5)
        if array.size(s5) > 0 and s5r5_show
            array.shift(s5)
    is_change := true
else
    if is_daily_based and custom_years_divisor == -1
        pivotX_high := math.max(pivotX_high, sec_high)
        pivotX_low := math.min(pivotX_low, sec_low)
    else
        pivotX_high := math.max(pivotX_high, high)
        pivotX_low := math.min(pivotX_low, low)

if barstate.islast and array.size(arr_time) > 0 and is_change
    is_change := false
    if array.size(arr_time) > 2 and custom_years_divisor > 0
        last_pivot_time = array.get(arr_time, array.size(arr_time) - 1)
        prev_pivot_time = array.get(arr_time, array.size(arr_time) - 2)
        estimate_pivot_time = last_pivot_time - prev_pivot_time
        array.push(arr_time, last_pivot_time + estimate_pivot_time)
    else
        array.push(arr_time, time_close(resolution))

    for i = 0 to array.size(lines) - 1
        if array.size(lines) > 0
            line.delete(array.shift(lines))
        if array.size(lines) > 0
            label.delete(array.shift(labels))

    for i = 0 to array.size(arr_time) - 2
        if array.size(p) > 0 and p_show
            draw_line(i, p, p_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(p, i), "P", p_color)
        if array.size(r1) > 0 and s1r1_show
            draw_line(i, r1, s1r1_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(r1, i), "R1", s1r1_color)
        if array.size(s1) > 0 and s1r1_show
            draw_line(i, s1, s1r1_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(s1, i), "S1", s1r1_color)
        if array.size(r2) > 0 and s2r2_show
            draw_line(i, r2, s2r2_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(r2, i), "R2", s2r2_color)
        if array.size(s2) > 0 and s2r2_show
            draw_line(i, s2, s2r2_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(s2, i), "S2", s2r2_color)
        if array.size(r3) > 0 and s3r3_show
            draw_line(i, r3, s3r3_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(r3, i), "R3", s3r3_color)
        if array.size(s3) > 0 and s3r3_show
            draw_line(i, s3, s3r3_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(s3, i), "S3", s3r3_color)
        if array.size(r4) > 0 and s4r4_show
            draw_line(i, r4, s4r4_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(r4, i), "R4", s4r4_color)
        if array.size(s4) > 0 and s4r4_show
            draw_line(i, s4, s4r4_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(s4, i), "S4", s4r4_color)
        if array.size(r5) > 0 and s5r5_show
            draw_line(i, r5, s5r5_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(r5, i), "R5", s5r5_color)
        if array.size(s5) > 0 and s5r5_show
            draw_line(i, s5, s5r5_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(s5, i), "S5", s5r5_color)
```

Manu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four operators to know here.

1. `=` is used when you declare a variable.
2. `:=` is used when you want to assign a new value to an already declared variable.
3. `[]` is called history reference operator and used when you want to access historical data of a variable. For example, `close[1]` returns the close price of one bar ago.
4. `nz()`: Replaces NaN values with zeros (or given value) in a series.

Now, let's look at the following code:

```
pivotX_prev_low = float(na)
pivotX_prev_low := nz(pivotX_prev_low[1])
```

`pivotX_prev_low = float(na)`: declare a new variable of `float` type called `pivotX_prev_low` and give it `na` as initial value.

`pivotX_prev_low := nz(pivotX_prev_low[1])`: Now assign `pivotX_prev_low`'s previous value to `pivotX_prev_low`.

To understand this last part, know that your script will be executed on each bar. When you want to have some constant information when you go from one bar to the next, this is how you (used to) do it. Because it will keep updating its value with the previous value, so its value will remain the same.

Lastly, `nz()` is used because for the very first bar of the chart, there is no historical data. `[1]` would return `NaN` (remember, it is the first bar so there is no `[1]`) and that might mess up your calculations.

Now, this is a traditional way to do this. Starting from `//@version=4`, you can use the `var` keyword for this purpose.

```
var pivotX_prev_low = float(na)
```

> The **var** keyword declares a variable and initializes it only once. This
> allows the value of the variable to be automatically saved between
> bars from the moment of initialization or the last assignment.

So, until you do `pivotX_prev_low := newVal`, it will keep its value from the previous bars.

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer, it's clearer

It's a different way to think than other languages. I'm understanding.

I've tried to plot pivotX_prev_low. I got this

![https://imgur.com/a/NWCvaPe](https://imgur.com/a/NWCvaPe)

My chart is in 1h candlestick. However with [1] it should take the previous value, but It have the same value for several days. I can't figure out why. If I was in 1-day, 4h, 1h, 1m it should adapt data from isn't it?

This is a Tradingview script updated for v5 :-)

Comment: Can you edit your question and share your whole code?

Comment: Done.

I've just add "plot(pivotX_prev_low, color=color.red)" just after the line you pasted.

I'm thinking it's the pivot_time_frame which control that, but variable is init before the the input is used. Crazy

Comment: Okay, it's a long script but from what I can see, the value of `pivotX_prev_low` is getting updated later in the script at two points. So, it might be related to that. But your assumption is correct, when you change the timeframe, it will adapt the data.

Comment: I'm understanding. I will look at that. It's very a different way to think.

Many thanks for your help.